# Calculate spatial data

Tags: php, laravel, geometry, spatial

I have below code.

```
$zone = RestaurantZones::whereRaw( "ST_Distance(circle_coordinates, ?) <= radius", [$point] )->pluck( 'id' );
```

I am getting the below error.

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error:
> 3055 Geometry byte string must be little endian.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following...

```
$point = DB::raw("ST_GeomFromWKB(ST_AsBinary(?))", [$yourGeometryData]);
$zone = RestaurantZones::whereRaw("ST_Distance(circle_coordinates, ?) <= radius", [$point])->pluck('id');
```